# What is static and dynamic scheduling on GPUs?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

GTX 4xx, 5xx (Fermi) had dynamic scheduling and GTX 6xx (Kepler) switched to static scheduling.

- What is static and dynamic scheduling in the context of GPUs?
- How does the design choice of static vs. dynamic affect the performance of real world compute workloads?
- Is there anything that can be done in code to optimize an algorithm for static or dynamic scheduling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're referring to static/dynamic [*instruction* scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_scheduling) in hardware.

Dynamic instruction scheduling means that the processor may re-order the individual instructions at runtime. This usually involves some bit of hardware that will try to predict the best order for whatever is in the instruction pipeline. On the GPUs you mentioned, this refers to the re-ordering of instructions for each individual warp.

The reason for switching from a dynamic scheduler back to a static scheduler is described in the [GK110 Architecture Whitepaper](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/content/PDF/kepler/NVIDIA-Kepler-GK110-Architecture-Whitepaper.pdf) as follows:

> We also looked for opportunities to optimize the power in the SMX warp
>   scheduler logic. For example, both Kepler and Fermi schedulers contain
>   similar hardware units to handle the scheduling function, including:
>
> - Register scoreboarding for long latency operations (texture and
>     load)
> - Inter‐warp scheduling decisions (e.g., pick the best warp to go
>     next among eligible candidates)
> - Thread block level scheduling (e.g., the GigaThread engine)
>
> However, Fermi’s scheduler also contains a complex hardware stage to
>   prevent data hazards in the math datapath itself. A multi‐port
>   register scoreboard keeps track of any registers that are not yet
>   ready with valid data, and a dependency checker block analyzes
>   register usage across a multitude of fully decoded warp instructions
>   against the scoreboard, to determine which are eligible to issue.
>
> For Kepler, we recognized that this information is deterministic (the
>   math pipeline latencies are not variable), and therefore it is
>   possible for the compiler to determine up front when instructions will
>   be ready to issue, and provide this information in the instruction
>   itself. This allowed us to replace several complex and power‐expensive
>   blocks with a simple hardware block that extracts the pre‐determined
>   latency information and uses it to mask out warps from eligibility at
>   the inter‐warp scheduler stage.

So basically, they're trading chip complexity, i.e. a simpler scheduler, for efficiency. But that potentially lost efficiency is now picked up by the compiler which can predict the best order, at least for the math pipeline.

As for your final question, i.e. what can be done in code to optimize an algorithm for static or dynamic scheduling, my personal recommendation would be to *not* use any inline assembler and just let the compiler/scheduler do its thing.

Comment: Thank you, @Pedro, just what I was looking for. The whitepaper is on my reading list now. I took a look at some SASS disassembly for Kepler and didn't see the extra latency information. It's probably just not being shown though. It sound like dynamic instruction scheduling is the same as out of order execution on CPUs.

Comment: The wording in the whitepaper is a bit odd. It sounds like they're saying that they already had fixed length pipelines in Fermi and that they just realized they could use that fact to enable static instruction scheduling without any loss in performance. The impression I get from around the web though, is that it's harder now to reach the theoretical maximum with real world compute workloads. So it seems more like they made two changes, going to a fixed length pipeline and then using that as a basis for a switch to static scheduling.

Comment: A lot changed in Kepler. In particular, ALUs quadrupled, while registers only doubled and shared memory stayed the same. That is really painful. Dynamic scheduling is not true out-of-order execution, and I think it's a very reasonable decision to calculate this ahead of time. I just wonder how they make memory-fetch stalls dynamic when regular ALU stalls are handled statically.